# Waterproofing fibreglass door

Tags: doors, paint, fiberglass

I have a fiberglass door exposed to elements and the paint is starting to peel off. Can I spray any waterproof coat or sealer for wood surfaces from home improvement stores to protect the pain. The paint dept. people at Home Depot recommended Rust-Oleum Painters Touch Clear Coat Gloss for Wood/Plastic/Metal. Any thoughts on how I can protect my fiberglass door paint without repainting.
[image]

Comment: i think that the peeling part is just a plastic frame around the glass insert. it may not even be fiberglass.

Comment: Will using Rust-Oleum Painters Touch Clear Coat Gloss hurt the paint or fiberglass door.